# Kubuntu how to make close button hit screen corner

Tags: kubuntu, mouse, kde, window-buttons

on Windows, I could just throw my mouse somewhere to the top right and then always hit the close button, if the window was maximized. On Kubuntu/KDE however, the circle hitbox doesn't hit the most top-right point of my screen. Is there any way, to make the button's hitbox so large, that I would hit it, if my mouse is is in the most top right corner, while the drawn button is still as small, tidy and circle-like, as ever? I would love to keep my current theme.
Also, I tested all square button themes that came with Kubuntu, but no themed button seems to hit the most top right corner.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1320323/

Answer (score 1):

I was able to accomplish this with some `gtk.css` styles. Note that this won't affect programs that set their own window titlebar styling, like Firefox, for example.

1. Create a file named `gtk.css` in `~/.config/gtk-3.0`.
2. Enter this CSS code, which removes the space to the right of the close button and makes the buttons fill the height of the window titlebar.

   ```css
   headerbar {
     padding-right: 0;
   }

   .titlebutton {
     min-width: 44px;
     min-height: 44px;
     padding: 0;
     margin: 0;
   }
   ```
3. Save the file, then log out and back in to apply the changes.

I wasn't able to figure out how to only increase the click target and keep the rendered button the same size, but this is the next-best thing.

Comment: What is the equivalent of this for gtk4 applications like Nautilus under 22.10? I tried to put a similar file under `~/.config/gtk-4.0`, but it didn't work.